# Is C# .NET Serializer Atomic?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

Straight forward question. If CPU crashes during serialization, will the file be corrupted?

Example of .NET Serialization C#:

```
    public bool TrySerializeToXML<T>(String FilePath, T t, XmlAttributeOverrides XmlAttributeOverrides = null)
    {
        lock (SerializationLock)
        {
            XmlSerializer Serializer = null;
            try
            {
                if (XmlAttributeOverrides == null) Serializer = new XmlSerializer(t.GetType());
                else Serializer = new XmlSerializer(t.GetType(), XmlAttributeOverrides);
                using (TextWriter TextWriter = new StreamWriter(FilePath))
                {
                    Serializer.Serialize(TextWriter, t);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The CPU never crashes, it merely tells you what you did wrong when you use C#.  Use C++ if you favor an undiagnosable crash that nobody can help you with.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes i understand... jeez.. common sense. I mean anything that happens during the operation will it cause the written file to be corrupted? or partially written

Comment: The file will be corru

Comment: That was a lot funnier then I intended it to be, sorry.  My wife give me funny looks.  I ought to be more helpful: use transactional saves.  First save to a file with a temporary name.  If nothing went wrong then rename it to the file it should be.  The File.Replace() overload with three arguments is important to get this right.

Comment: There should be *League Tables* of comments of the day, i think that would win for today

Comment: Never `catch { return false; }`. This discards the stack trace, error message, and error type, making debugging very difficult. It's way too easy to ignore the return value and try to continue as if nothing went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `XmlSerializer` works on a stream
2. That stream in this case is a `FileStream`
3. A `FileStream` works on a flushable Buffer (of default 4k), meaning when the buffer reaches its max it will flush it to disk

If application crashes or serialisation error happens during serialisation you are likely to have no (or only partial data) flushed to disk

Also *Atomic* is debatably the wrong word to use here, either way it definitely is'nt *Atomic*